# NSNotificationCenter calling methods from super class or subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have a view controller **B** which is subclass of **A**.I have registered for a notification named  **kMyNotificaitonName** in  in **A’s** **ViewWillAppear** like this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MyNotificaitonNameHandler:) name: kMyNotificaitonName object:nil];
```

I have implemented **MyNotificaitonNameHandler** in view controller **A** and **B** which method will get called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the particular object. If you've created an instance of A it will be A. And otherwise. Since your B class provides implementation of `MyNotificaitonNameHandler` and you have instance of B then it's B. Pure OOP

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I am registering in in A’s ViewWillAppear. then which will be called? You mean which is unpredictable?

Comment: @jailani I understand. I have read your question thoroughly. I don't say it depends on WHERE you've added your object as observer, I say it depends on WHAT TYPE of class your object is. You wrote "I have a view controller B" it means B's implementation will be called

Comment: @jailani it's 100 percent predictable. It only depends on the type of the object and nothing else. It's polymorphism